# thread synchronization during warp unrolling in CUDA

Tags: cuda, synchronization, nvidia

I'm trying to get my head around the reduction technique #5 in the [reduction in CUDA](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) by Mark Harris.

Reduction #5 improves the previous reduction #4 by applying the last warp unrolling.

Slide 21 mentions: "we don't need to `__syncthreads()`", and that's the part I don't understand.

Here is a code with the main logic:

```
__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int* sdata, int tid) {
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32]; // line A
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16]; // line B
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
}

// later...
for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>32; s>>=1) {
  if (tid < s)
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
  __syncthreads();
}
if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
```

I don't understand why there is no `__syncthreads()` between line **A** and line **B** (and between the next lines as well).

**my question**: is it possible that within the same warp one thread executes line **B** prior to the other thread executes line **A**? (seems like it is not possible, could anyone please confirm and elaborate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible that within the same warp one thread executes line B prior to the other thread executes line A?

At the time that was written (which was about 10 years ago), there was no possibility of that occurring, because warps were guaranteed to execute in lock step. Note that the memory in question needed to be declared `volatile` to prevent compiler optimization from caching results between reduction steps for Fermi and newer GPUs. On the original Tesla architecture that was not required.

However, the state-of-the-art way to perform warp level operations has changed and that type of design pattern is potentially unsafe on some of the very latest architectures. Instead, you should prefer warp level primitives for a reduction rather than implicit warp synchronization. See [this blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/) for more information.